# Efficient and easy way to extract data from divs taken from website

Tags: php, html, arrays, json

Hi a have 100 such elements * 40 files = 4000 elements. 
I want to extract src and href from each element and write it to array to simply send it to database

```
<a class="market_listing_row_link" href="http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/FAMAS%20%7C%20Colony%20%28Minimal%20Wear%29" id="resultlink_99">
<div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row market_listing_searchresult" id="result_99">
            <img id="result_99_image" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/fWFc82js0fmoRAP-qOIPu5THSWqfSmTELLqcUywGkijVjZYMUrsm1j-9xgEObwgfEh_nvjlWhNzZCveCDfIBj98xqodQ2CZknz59Ne60Iwh0fTvREaFdWco39RrlByIN5M5kXMP49bhWKA3utIrGYLl-M4pJH5PRWaLSNFz5ux1pg_dbeZyPoyvui3i6PnBKBUQvkKsHsA/62fx62f" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="" />      
            <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
        <span class="market_table_value">
            Starting at:<br/>
            <span style="color:white">&#36;0.05 USD</span>
        </span>
        <span class="market_arrow_down" style="display: none"></span>
        <span class="market_arrow_up" style="display: none"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_num_listings">
        <span class="market_table_value">
            <span class="market_listing_num_listings_qty">6,191</span>
        </span>
    </div>

            <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
        <span id="result_99_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;">FAMAS | Colony (Minimal Wear)</span>
        <br/>
        <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
    </div>
</div>
</a>
```

Comment: This isn't a coding service or a freelance work site. You should demonstrate some effort on your own part before asking for help here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Simple HTML Dom: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

It will let you go through the HTML using the DOM instead of having to manually parse through everything.